# SoapSerializationEnvelope Property position

Tags: java, android, soap

**I create a SoapSerializationEnvelope, but I can't define the property position to before the nested SoapObject:**

```
SoapObject ajanlat = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "ajanlat");
SoapObject alapadatok = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_DATA_CONTRACT, "Alapadatok");

PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_DATA_CONTRACT);
    pi.setName("Azonosito");
    pi.setValue("1234"); 
ajanlat.addProperty(pi);

alapadatok.addProperty(getProperty("SzerzodeskotesOka", "2"));
ajanlat.addSoapObject(alapadatok);

final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.dotNet = true;             
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;      
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(ajanlat);
```

**This is generate the following request XML:**

```
<n0:ajanlat xmlns:n0="http://www.signal.hu">
<n1:Alapadatok xmlns:n1="http://www.signal.hu/DataContract">
    <n1:SzerzodeskotesOka i:type="d:string">2</n1:SzerzodeskotesOka>
</n1:Alapadatok>
<n4:Azonosito i:type="d:string" xmlns:n4="http://www.signal.hu/DataContract>1234</n4:Azonosito>
</n0:ajanlat>
```

**But I need the following:**

```
<n0:ajanlat xmlns:n0="http://www.signal.hu">
<n4:Azonosito i:type="d:string" xmlns:n4="http://www.signal.hu/DataContract">1234</n4:Azonosito>
<n1:Alapadatok xmlns:n1="http://www.signal.hu/DataContract">
    <n1:SzerzodeskotesOka i:type="d:string">2</n1:SzerzodeskotesOka>
</n1:Alapadatok>
</n0:ajanlat>
```